# How to change line length in UITableView swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I'm using a tableview in my app that has lines not reaching until the end of the row:

[image]

In my design I need some of the lines to reach all the way like in this picture:

[image]

Also another problem I have is that I see the last line in the tableview:

[image]

My question is
how do I make some of the lines all the way across like in the 2nd picture
and another question is
how do I remove the last line of the UITableView ?

Comment: lines are tableview saperator ?

Comment: Any specific reasons to use `UITableView` here? Why nota a combination of customized UITextfields and UIButtons?

Comment: tableviewcontroller with static cells can achieve almost all screens. Main reason is that it can automatically adjust the scrolling(which i bother most.). also easy to add constaints for textfields in static cell.

Comment: Optional you can add in your cell a view and use it as separator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use below code for the tableviewcells in which you want it to be touched to edge of tableview.

```
cell.separatorInset = UIEdgeInsets.zero
cell.layoutMargins = UIEdgeInsets.zero
```

Note: As tableview uses reusable cells, so if you are setting `separatorInset` and `layoutMargins`, then make sure you are setting it for all cells. Otherwise reused cell will have different separator inset then expected. So, for other cells, keep left=16 in `UIEdgeInsets`.

for case of hiding the separator case, you have to again play with `separatorInset`

```
 cell.separatorInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, UIScreen.main.bounds.width)
```

Comment: where do i refer to the specific cells ? i cannot connect them regularly

Comment: can you also add a way to remove the seperator line ? (as what i want to do in my last section)

Comment: @ChiefMadog : Check the updated answer, Actually i haven't read your full question, so missed that thing. But now its clear

Answer (score 0):

add a view with light gray background with height of 1 and append to the top of cell. customize in each cell as you needed.

Answer (score 0):

1. You are using custom cell so you can use label/view for line, set the label/view leading and trailing constraints or update label/view height, color according to your requirements and set the table view  separator None.
2. Set the condition for last row of table in Table cellForRowAt function and hide the label/view.

Answer (score 0):

You can change insets of seperator for last cell in tableview so it will disappear from screen.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "TableviewCell", for: indexPath) as! TableviewCell

    if indexPath.row == LastCount {
        cell.separatorInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: UIScreen.main.bounds.width*2, bottom: 1, right: -(UIScreen.main.bounds.width*3))
    }
    else
    {
        cell.separatorInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0)
    }
    return cell
}
```

Answer (score 0):

to remove that last line or all other lines you have set `tableView.tableFooter = UIView()` in cellForRowAt

Answer (score 0):

**For Xcode 15 and Swift 5 on Storyboard**

Inside Storyboard of Attribute Inspector make Sperator Inset Custom and you can give leading and trailing inset.

[image]

[image]